# I'm trying to execute this expression in c and have confusion regarding its output-

Tags: c

```
int x=2,z=0;
z=++x*x++*++x;
printf("%d,%d",x,z);
int x=2,z=0;
z=++x*++x*++x;
printf("%d,%d",x,z);
```

//giving output 5,36, and 5,80. help me please.

Comment: Undefined behavior. There is no need of anything like this in the code which leads to UB.

Comment: What do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Brackets are your friends (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: 'I'm trying to execute this expression in c' - why?  Do you want to get fired or barred from the course?  You realise that all code like this is utter crap, right?   Are you trolling?

Comment: Oh...'member for today' troll :(